# problem about semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ be an interval and $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a function. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

a) $f$ is lower semicontinuous at the point $a$;

b) given a sequence $x_n \in I, x_n \rightarrow a \Rightarrow \liminf \ f(x_n) \geq f(a)$.

My doubt:

$f$ is lower semicontinuous at the point $a$ $\Rightarrow x \in I, |x-a|< \delta \Rightarrow f(x) > f(a) - \varepsilon$ $\Rightarrow x_n \in I, |x_n - a|< \delta \Rightarrow f(x_n) > f(a) - \varepsilon$.

But in that case, $f(a) = \liminf \ f(x_n)$ because, by definition, $\liminf \ f(x_n) - \varepsilon < f(x_n) < \limsup \ f(x_n) + \varepsilon$

And I can't get the desired result. I'd like some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $\Rightarrow$ b):
Suppose $f$ is lsc. at $a$, and suppose $x_n \to a$. Let $\epsilon>0$, then for some $\delta$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $f(x) > f(a)-\epsilon$. Hence $f(x_n) > f(a) -\epsilon$ for $n$ suitably large, hence $\liminf_n f(x_n) \ge f(a) -\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we are finished.

b) $\Rightarrow$ a):
I am not a fan of contradiction, but it seems easiest here:
Suppose b) is true, but $f$ is not lsc. Then there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ we can find $x$ such that $|x-a|< \delta$ and $f(x) \le f(a)-\epsilon$. Choosing $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ gives a sequence $x_n \to a$ that satisfies $\liminf f(x_n) \le f(a) -\epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.